# MAC - NPM - VSTS - inserting a registry AND token into global npmrc file

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, registry, azure-devops

I need to add a global registry to my computer for a project I am working on. It cannot reside locally in the project - I know this works, but for the sake of this project I can't keep it there.

I have tried npm config set registry... but I am working through VSTS, and it provides an already generated token.  When I attempted it, after setting it, entering username/pw/email... it returned:

> Registry returned 404 for PUT on undefined npm ERR!

There are options for windows only:

> Recommended (for Windows users):Install and run the auth helper
>
> npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com
>   --always-auth false
>
> vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc

But the alternative is to add it manually.  It gives me a token, and I just need to somehow add this globally... and I have found zero online that has helped.

Just searched and found this... irony? 
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I did not...

Answer (score 3):

you can go to finder and Hold down the Command, Shift and H keys: cmd + shift + H. It will take you to home directory. npmrc file usually be saved there if its configured to be global. If you don't see it there, Hold down the Command, Shift and Period keys: cmd + shift + [.]. It will display all hidden file in that directory. You can then see it. Right click on it and open it using text editor and add required entries.

If the .npmrc file is still not there in hidden files list, then .npmrc file is not configured to be global. you can create one in this directory using touch command on mac.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy the generated token and paste to .npmrc file in $home for mac system.

More information: [Set up your client's npmrc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/npm/npmrc?view=vsts)

Comment: Thank you for responding. But I can't seem to actually even locate that file. I've been at the link you've sent me. But doesn't help without being able to manually see/access that file.  When I tried: ~/.npmrc, I got a permission denied.  Even though I am logged into npm.

Comment: Try to open open Finder with Command-Shift-H shortcut, then Go> 
 Home

Comment: @steven.gissubel Do you find .npmrc file?

Comment: No, I haven't found the file yet.  Even though npm config tells me it exists.

Comment: You may have to create the file if it doesn't exist. It should be located at `~/.npmrc` (aka `$HOME/.npmrc` aka `/Users/[user]/.npmrc`). That said, I am also having trouble getting this process to work on macOS.

Comment: @Kevin did you sort it out ? I got this error on a mac vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc 
zsh: exec format error: vsts-npm-auth

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall.